# jquery appended button click not working on dom

Tags: jquery, append

I put some html-code via .append() in a bootstrap-modal window (this works) in a loop out of localstorage:

```
$(".abschick").on("click",function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();

zaehler2 = localStorage.getItem("zaehler");
namen = localStorage["names"];
$(".produkteliste").empty();
for (var i = 0; i <= zaehler2; i++) {
$(".produkteliste").append($('<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6  
produktboxer'+i+';">' + localStorage.getItem("names_"+i) + '<input 
type="hidden" name="produkt_'+i+'" 
value="'+localStorage.getItem("names_"+i)+'"/></div>'+'<div 
id="produktboxer2'+i+'" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 produktboxer2'+i+'">
<button type="button"  class="btn-default outline entfernen'+i+';" 
style="width:200px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" 
style="left:20px;padding-left:-20px;" aria-hidden="true">
</span>entfernen</button></div>').on('click', handleClick));
}

});
function handleClick(){
alert("halo"); //works
$(.produktboxer0).hide(); //doesnt work
}

$(".entfernen0").on("click", handleClick);
```

The alert works but when I try something binding on dom it doesnt work.
Can anyone see the mistake?

Comment: You see that `$(.produktboxer0).hide();` is invalid? Hint: `$('.produktboxer0')`

Comment: Exactly. It should hide the appended layer.